# QuickBook Desktop Integration with PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

My requirement is to connect quickbook desktop with PHP app. For that I just go through http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector to create QWC file, found parameters like ***FileID, OwnerID***.

How can I get this from quickbook desktop..?

Thanks in advance for the responses...

Answer (score 0):

Copy-pasted right from the link you posted:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector#example_qwc_file

Copy/paste:

```
<FileID>…</FileID> You can make this up as long as it follows the GUID format (uppercase HEX chars only!): {6904A826-7368-11DC-8317-F7AD55D89593}. It has something to do with DataExt elements; most simple integrations can just make this up.
<OwnerID>…</OwnerID> Same as above
```

Comment: Hello

In QuickBook Desktop with the aid of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066883/quickbook-desktop-integration-with-php I just created the .QWC file. Now I'm in behind how to create customers for quickbookDesktop from php. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Comments are not really the best place to discuss that. Ask another question, but SEARCH GOOGLE first as there are tons of examples of doing this already out there.